# Excel Click sale form button

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to coding, and i am trying to set up a simple POS for my snack Shack in the Shop. the code works, but i have many items to sell. i have the mainline macro to locate the buttons, im just wondering if there's a way to input the result from cs to the .Range() this way i wont have to change up the code manually in each row, rather than having one code that will self locate the button and automatically select the cell and input its value.

```
Sub btn1_Click2()
Static value As Integer
value = value + 1
'Mainlineup Macro
Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
With b.TopLeftCell
cs = .Row
End With
Worksheets(1).Range("D$").value = value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good effort! It should be helped by your starting to think in terms of cells and their value. Every cell is a "range", but not - by a far sigh - is every range a cell.

Start by ceding the use of the reserved word "Value" to Excel. If you use the same word to identify one of your variables there will be confusion, both for you and for Excel. There will be unexplainable "bugs" in Excel.

`Range("D$")` doesn't define a cell because a cell has both a row and a column. The term will throw an error, which is predictable because the term neither defines a range nor a cell.

When you define a cell in VBA I suggest you use row & column to define it, like `ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 5)` which is "E3" in worksheet parlance. VBA does understand `ActiveSheet.Range("E3")`. So the real question is whether you do. Once you start manipulating cells and ranges using Row & Column is a lot easier because it is easier to calculate numbers than names.

Unfortunately, I don't understand your intention. However, you are on the right track by assigning a value to the `Value` property of a cell. You can also assign a value to the `Value` property of a range, but `Range("D:D").Value = 4` will assign the same value to every cell in column D.

Perhaps this is what you had in mind. `Worksheets(1).Range("D" & Cstr(cs))).Value = value`. I would write that like this: `Worksheets(1).Cells(cs, 4).Value = value`. Perhaps `Worksheets(1).Cells(cs, "D").Value = value` would be a compromise.

Just in case, I point out that `b.TopLeftCell` is a cell (and therefore also a range) and therefore has a `Value` property. Code like `Worksheets(1).Cells(cs, 4).Value = b.TopLeftCell.Value` would be perfectly legitimate and do what you expect it to do by the looks of it.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. i actually had .Range("D2"). The button did its job using the code i had. i just wanted one macro that would work for all the buttons. Thanks to your help i accomplished this. I ended up rewriting the code to:

Comment: `Sub btn1_Click2()`
`Static value As Integer`  
`' Mainlineup Macro`  
`Dim b As Object, cs As Integer`  
`Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)`  
`With b.TopLeftCell ` 
`cs = .Row ` 
`End With`  
`value = Worksheets(1).Cells(cs, 5).value + 1`
`Worksheets(1).Cells(cs, 5).value = value`
`End Sub`